# TypeScript - How to dynamically create class?

Tags: javascript, typescript, class

I have 2 classes:

```
class First {
  constructor(name, age) {
    // do something
  }
}

class Second {
  constructor(name, URL, topic) {
    // do something else
  }
}
```

Now, let's say I have the following function that will create an instance of one of those 2 classes, based on the params passed (classname and class' params (params)):

```
create(classname, params) {
  // return "new" instance of class ${classname} with params 
  // something like:
  // return new ${classname}(params)
}
```

Any idea how I can achieve that? Is there a "TypeScript" way of doing that? Of course, i would like to avoid the "if / else" statement or even the "switch case" approach.

Thanks o/

Comment: Why do you need to do this?

Comment: You could do [this](https://tsplay.dev/NleL5m)

Comment: Thanks! Seems to match my problem indeed! Quick question, how can i call the function like that => create("First", {name: "lol", age: 32})`?

Comment: I've been able to do [this](https://tsplay.dev/Wo5kjN), but there is still a (non blocking?) issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @kelly, I've been able to fix it with the following:

- Create an object "classes" with all the needed objects in it

```
const classes = {
  First,
  Second
}
```

- Use the following

```
return new classes[classname as keyof typeof classes](params);
```